# Plotting fitted linear regression that is multiplied by a factor of k

Tags: r

Plotting a simple linear regression has the code

```
plot(X,Y, pch=16)
```

where Y_i=b_0 + b_1X_i and the fitted line is

```
abline(lm(Y~X))
```

Then what would the code be for the fitted value Y_hat if X is multiplied by a factor of k?
Would it be

```
abline(k*lm(Y~X))
```

since k * Y_hat = k * b_0 + k * b_1 * X_i?

Answer (score 0):

That won't directly work this way, because you can't multiply an `"lm"` object with something. However, you may draw the regression line in different ways, using `stats:::plot.lm method`, intercept and slope, and plotting the (ordered) fitted values.

```
## baseline regression
(fit0 <- lm(y ~ x, d))$coe
# (Intercept)           x 
#    1.111633    3.427159 

op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 3))  ## set pars

plot(y ~ x, d, main="line.fit")
abline(fit0)  ## line by stats:::plot.lm method

plot(y ~ x, d, main="line.coef")
abline(a=fit0$coefficients[1], b=fit0$coefficients[2])  ## intercept and slope

plot(y ~ x, d, main="line.fitted")
lines(sort(d$x), fit0$fitted.values[order(d$x)])  ## (ordered) fitted values
```

[image]

Now, let's multiply `x` of our example data (see below) by `k` to get `xk`.

```
k <- 1e5
d <- transform(d, xk=x * k)
(fit.k <- lm(y ~ xk, d))$coe
#  (Intercept)           xk 
# 1.111633e+00 3.427159e-05
```

We can see only the slope changes compared to `fit0`, it is *divided* by `k`. The intercept stays the same. Accordingly, we apply this insight to our plotting methods.

```
plot(y ~ xk, d, main="line.fit");abline(fit.k)

plot(y ~ xk, d, main="line.coef")
abline(a=fit.k$coefficients[1], b=fit.k$coefficients[2], col="black")
abline(a=fit0$coefficients[1], b=fit0$coefficients[2]/k, lty=2, col="red")

plot(y ~ xk, d, main="line.fitted");lines(sort(d$xk), fit0$fitted.values[order(d$x)])

par(op)  ## reset pars
```

[image]

The middle plot demonstrates that the fit line of `fit.k` coincides with the line where we multiply the intercept of `fit0` by `k`.

---

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(42)
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1e2))
d <- transform(d, y=1.2 + 3.4*x + rnorm(1e2))
```